# How to design a application security architecture across multiple technology stack

Tags: security, architecture

Due to acquisition, we have lot of modules using different technology. We are considering a way to centralize application security controls implementation. Two solutions in my mind but both seems have some flaws:
Option1
Create a independent security library. The weakness is it cannot be used for different language. We will need at least provide interface for different language.

Option2
Create a security service using REST API. Then, any technology can use it. But it introduce extra performance overhead.

Do you have any experience on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider [XACML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XACML) as an option:

> XACML stands for eXtensible Access Control Markup Language. The
>   standard defines a declarative access control policy language
>   implemented in XML and a processing model describing how to evaluate
>   authorization requests according to the rules defined in policies.

It might be suitable for you, because it really allows to have fully centralized access control. You will only need to have a PEP (Policy Enforcement Point) implemented for every particular module.

> The XACML model supports and encourages the separation of the
>   authorization decision from the point of use. When authorization
>   decisions are baked into client applications, it is very difficult
>   to update the decision criteria when the governing policy changes.
>   When the client is decoupled from the authorization decision,
>   authorization policies can be updated on the fly and affect all
>   clients immediately.